# How to get current location ( latitude, longtitude). Not use get IP?

Tags: python

I want to get the current location (in views.py) without having to use the IP to determine (because it's incorrect)

Answer (score 0):

what about using the W3C Geolocation Api? It seems that it provides reliable location information, though INDIRECTLY, through cross-validation with local providers such as the WiFi network and so on. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W3C_Geolocation_API

Comment: How directly or indirectly it is depends on the client. It *may* use super accurate GPS. Either way it’s not [tag:python] though.

Comment: I want to wirte code in views, not write script in html

Comment: @duydo Then the IP is all you can possibly use.